# Changes for upload_max_filesize, memory_limit & post_max_size in the php.ini aren't affect

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to increase the `upload_max_filesize` etc in order to import bigger files with phpMyAdmin.

I have changed the `php.ini` and restart Apache. I can see the changes on the phpMyAdmin import screen (mentioned there Max: 300MiB) but when I try to import a 50MB file I'm getting the alert:

```
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.
```

Any idea how it can be: In 1 hand it seems the changes took affect but in the other hand it doesn't work...

Answer (score 15):

The solution copy from [link](http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2008/04/14/changing-the-php-file-upload-limit-in-ubuntu-linux/)

If you have your own Ubuntu server running you may encounter the maximal file size upload limit in php scripts which is set to 2Mb as default. In order to change that we first have a look what the size actually is. In /var/www (standard www directory) create a file called info.php with the following content:

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then browse to this file via **localhost/info.php** (replace localhost with the servername if necessary) and look for the line

```
upload_max_filesize 2M 2M
```

which will show you the actual maximum file size. In order to change that open a ssh connection to your server and edit the file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini with

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

search for “upload_max_filesize” with Ctrl-W and change “2M” to “20M”. Save the file with Ctrl-O and exit with Ctrl-X. Restart the apache server with either

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and also restart fpm:

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

and visit again **localhost/info.php** to check if the maximum file size was changed. If you're not using php 7.4 obviously replace the number part with the php version you're using.

Comment: for php 7.2 I had to do this
`sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: Find the correct `php.ini` file in the output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Don't just restart apache, also restart fpm, like this: `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Comment: [php_ini_loaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php)  Retrieve a path to the loaded php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853301/phpmyadmin-file-import-error

> I've just fixed this on my own dev machine. In /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf you can see where phpmyadmin is trying to store temp files, e.g.:
>
> php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
>
> Make sure this is writable by the user that apache runs as and has free space.
> In my case, on my dev machine, I run apache as my own user rather than the normal www-data or apache user. That tmp dir wasn't writable by my user.

Comment: how do i give this folder permissions

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 other ways to change override `php.ini` settings.

1. Using `.user.ini` (**works only with`php-fpm`**):

   ***Warning:*** If you run PHP as an Apache module, from the commandline, or using the builtin-Server, the .user.ini-files are not processed.

   Create `.user.ini` file in your site's main directory and add these lines there:

   ```
   upload_max_filesize=300M
   post_max_size=300M
   memory_limit=300M
   ```
2. Using `.htaccess` file or vhost's config file (**works only with `libapache2-mod-php`**):

   ***Warning:*** This solution doesn't work with PHP FPM.

   If you are running PHP as an Apache module, it's also possible to override `php.ini` settings from Apache's vhost configs or from local `.htaccess` file.

   For example, you can add these to your `.htaccess`:

   ```
   php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
   php_value post_max_size 300M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When running PHP as FPM, you need to change different files:

`sudo nano /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini` (version number may vary)

and then

`sudo systemctl restart php8.2-fpm`

to restart the FPM engine.

Answer (score -1):

I have WordPress installed on Ubuntu and
I was having this problem on PHP version 8.1, Apache2 running on Ubuntu.

Steps to solve this problem:

1. Login to your server via `ssh`
2. `cd /etc/php/8.1/apache2` (replace 8.1 with your php version)
3. `nano php.ini`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and look for the line: `upload_max_filesize`
5. Update with desired limit for example: `upload_max_filesize = 512M`
6. Similarly look for `post_max_size` and update with desired value.
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save in nano editor
8. Run command: `sudo systemctl restart apache2` (to restart Apache2)

Check the limit again, it'll show the newly set limit.